# How to launch a resource jar from inside another java app - with Solution

Tags: java, resources

**EDITED with solution (below...)**

I have a Splash screen that is packaged into it's own jar.  It works.

I can call the Splash.jar from inside another java app by:

Desktop.getDesktop().open(new File("/Applications/Eclipse/Splash.jar"));

and it works just fine.  But, that's pretty limited.  So, I created a res folder in the new app and dragged the Splash.jar into it.

Now, how do I call it/run it from the main class of the new app??

I looked at all the related posts and see no clear approach...

Thanks

---

**SOLUTION:**

I found the solution - so simple. First, the credit to avjava.com for their clear and excellent tutorial on doing this  ( [Run Another Jar from a Jar](http://www.avajava.com/tutorials/lessons/how-do-i-run-another-application-from-java.html?page=2) ).  So, now I can run the Splash (or other .jar) just as hoped for.

**The answer is here - posted in the form of complete code:**

```
package test;

import java.io.IOException;

public class RuntimeExecTest1 {

  public static void main(String[] args) {
    try {
      System.out.println("TextEdit I hope");
      Runtime runTime = Runtime.getRuntime();

      Process process = runTime.exec(
          "java -jar /your directory/your app.jar");

      try {
        Thread.sleep(5000); // keep in open 5000ms
      } catch (InterruptedException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
      System.out.println("Closing TextEdit, I hope");
      process.destroy();        // kill the process of running the .jar
    } catch (IOException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We don't know how your existing Splash Screen works...

**Java AWT support for Splash Screen:**

If you are using the Java built-in support for splash screens (as specified in [SplashScreen Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/SplashScreen.html)) then you need to use a command line switch, or better yet, modify your MANIFEST file in order to reference your Splash Screen:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Main-Class: Test
SplashScreen-Image: filename.gif
```

I don't know if, for this particular case, you can reference files in a different JAR. In the worst case, you can unpack the existing JAR (they are just ZIP files) and get the image file in order to include it in your own main jar.

**Possibly custom Splash:**

If your Splash is created using custom code, then you need the documentation about how to load it. At least, you'd need to add Splash.jar to the *classpath* of your application and, from your app, call the necessary method or load the appropriate resource.

All the resources and classes contained in .jar files that are added to the *classpath* are available from your app.

Comment: I'll comment here, though it applies to the other responses, as well.  If any of you have made a splash via the java tutorial, you know that it gets packaged with a custom manifest and, via Eclipse, it's done by exporting a Jar (not a Deployable Jar). The deployable jar approach does not work with splash (at least not for me).  So, I need to use the Splash.jar as it is and not call any of its methods...  So, I'm looking for a simple call to the resource. If I add it to the classpath, I still need to know how to call it...  Thanks

Comment: Well, if you include the .jar in the classpath, you can find where the main() method of the Splash.jar is, and call it statically (i.e. `SplashMainClass.main(null)`), but this looks like a strange thing to do.

Comment: Thanks. The thing about splash is it must be contained along with manifest and resources, such as imgages in a jar.  Otherwise, they don't work - check the zillions of posts on java Splash.  It's in the classpath but, that isn't enough.  I need to have a way to call it to run it as if it were another app but now located in a resource folder inside the new app I'm writing.  I have no problems calling up images from a resource folder in my app and using them for icons - it seems like I should also be able to simply call another jar in the resource folder and run it...  But, how?

Comment: Perhaps I wasn't clear.  I built a splash screen identical to the Java tutorial at Oracle/java - only difference is the graphic image. Thus, the project has a manifest, the SplashScreen-Image listed.  I'm using Eclipse and there are two ways to export a jar: 1) Jar, 2) Deployable Jar.  Only the first one will create it so that it runs as a standalone app.  So, I have a splashscreen app I want to run from a new app by some kind of call to it. Yes, I can do it all in one app but, I'd prefer to have the splash as a quasi-runnable plug-in, so to speak. How to do it?  Calling it's class won't work.

Comment: First - thanks to everyone for your help!  After messing around enough, it looks like the best approach's are: 1) Simply load an image from the manifest, or 2) Use an undecorated JFrame or JWindow. I think I'll stick with the manifest approach. (JWindow needs hand-coding and not Image/icon friendly.  So, I have a solution.  Thanks again to everyone!

Answer (score 1):

You could create a new `URLClassLoader` with the Splash.jar and then use reflections to execute the main method.

```
URL[] urls = new URL[] { new URL("res/Splash.jar") };
ClassLoader cl = new URLClassLoader(urls);
Class<?> clazz = cl.loadClass("splash.Main");
Method method = clazz.getMethod("main", String[].class);
method.invoke(null, new String[0]);
```

Comment: Thanks.  Error:  "The constructor URLClassLoader(DocFlavor.URL[]) is undefined" I'm added what may be a clearer explaination/needs to comments for ijmontes, below.  I like the idea of the class loader but, I don't want to run the class, I want to run the .jar, just as if I ran it as a standalone app.

Comment: It seems you imported the wrong URL class, you need `java.net.URL`and not `javax.print.DocFlavor.URL`. If you run a jar the java executable does not do anything else. It creates a ClassLoader from the classpath, loads the main class and executes the main method. What is the advantage of running the jar, if that does the same as something you can do in Java yourself?

Comment: Thanks. I'll try the correct URL class.  Why do it this way? Well, hoping to make it a Bean (maybe not doable due to needing a manifest... not sure).  Guess I'd like one common splash screen to call and not need to mess with doing it in each app.  Plus, I like using Eclipse's Export Runnable Jar option - seems to work across all platforms I've tested.

Answer (score 0):

add the resource path to your CLASSPATH envoirment variable and you can use it without modifying your existing code

if your running linux

export CLASSPATH=yourpath;

and if your running windows:

from My Computer right click > properties

OR

if you dont want to add it to CLASSPATH ENV variable,

then

java -classpath="your path to jar" yourclass

Comment: Definitely adding something like this to the system CLASSPATH is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

Why not define Splash.jar as an external jar and go about using all its routines. Much like JDBC.